# List outside of function cannot be tested if members contain a space

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, scope, boolean

A have a function that takes a list and tests if the members of the list are equal to a value. If the value contains a space, this check fails. I used ord() on the target member and on the test value and the characters are indeed all the same.

My current workaround is to strip spaces from the list members, but this is not ideal.

Why is this happening? It seems like a major problem if a list called by a function can't actually be checked for membership if the members have spaces . . .

MWE:

```
list_ = ['a a', 'bb', 'cc']

for item in list_:
    print(item + ' == a a?\t', item is 'a a')

def function_():
    for item in list_:
        print(item + ' == a a?\t', item is 'a a')
function_()

def function_(list_):
    for item in list_:
        print(item + ' == a a?\t', item is 'a a')
function_(list_)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `is` operator is used to check whether two objects are the same object, but two identical strings don't necessarily point to the same position in memory. Instead, use the equality operator, `==`.

```
def function_():
    for item in list_:
        print(item + ' == a a?\t', item == 'a a')
```

Your `is` check succeeded in your first example because your interpreter performed an optimization that consolidated the two `'a a'` string literals into a single object in memory. In your other examples, the `'a a'` outside the function and the `'a a'` inside the function are in different scopes, so no such optimization occurs.